# Skydrive API: Easy way to determine the current path

Tags: onedrive

is there a way to determine the current path in respect to Skydrive directory structure, like the one shown at the top of the standard file picker (Someone's SkyDrive > some folder > another folder)?

Of course I can get it recursively by doing current folder properties call, for example

```
GET http://apis.live.net/v5.0/file.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!126
```

recording the folder name, then doing similar call for parent_id of the current folder and so on till the top. But is there an easier way to get the full path in a single call?